# How do I get my latest images using instagrams API without a user login?

Tags: java, api, oauth-2.0, instagram

I have been trying to work through the instagram API but I am caught up on getting the access token.  In the instagram API, it states:

> At this point, we present the user with a login screen and then a
>   confirmation screen where they approve your app’s access to his/her
>   Instagram data.

Now I was wondering what if you don't want the user to have to login?  For instance, say I have a site and I only want to display my latest images.  The user should not have to login to be able see these. However, all the endpoints(http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) to get a users media require the access_token provided by the user login.  How can I just get my latest images without a user login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which endpoint are you using?

The `GET/users/{user-id}/media/recent` endpoint requires authentication. So there is no way to get a specific users' media without an access token.

Comment: Exactly, I am wondering if there is a way to get them without the authentication.

Comment: Through the instagram api, i dont think it is possible. I have tried myself but the endpoint needs authentication. However you could try this third party site http://statigr.am/feed/[username] then parse the result

Comment: Thank you for providing that link, I think thats the route I'm going to have to use.  Cannot believe instagram makes the user authenticate like that.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, this seems to work without needing authentication:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USER_ID/media/recent/?client_id=CLIENT_ID

Answer (score 1):

You could generate an access token with your instagram account here: http://instagram.pixelunion.net/,

then use this url: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN to retrieve all the info about your latest 20 posts including images urls.